# Kubernetes node shows NotReady status

Tags: kubernetes, bare-metal

I had upgraded my cluster OS from `Ubuntu-18.04LTS` to `Ubuntu-20.04LTS`, Post upgrade our bare metal kubernetes cluster nodes are not running it remains in `NotReady` state.

```
$ kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME          STATUS     ROLES                  AGE    VERSION    INTERNAL-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
server01      Ready      control-plane,master   364d   v1.23.16   175.211.213.121   <none>        Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS   5.4.0-132-generic   docker://20.10.7
server02      NotReady   worker1                299d   v1.23.16   175.211.213.122   <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS   5.4.0-132-generic   docker://20.10.7
server03      NotReady   worker2                364d   v1.23.16   175.211.213.123   <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS   5.4.0-132-generic   docker://23.0.6
server04      NotReady   worker3                364d   v1.23.16   175.211.213.124   <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS   5.4.0-132-generic   docker://20.10.7
```

```
$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system -o wide
NAME                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS        AGE    IP                NODE          NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
coredns-bd6b6df9f-4gc8m               1/1     Running   14 (55m ago)    364d   10.244.0.30       server01      <none>           <none>
coredns-bd6b6df9f-9kh94               1/1     Running   13 (55m ago)    364d   10.244.0.29       server01      <none>           <none>
etcd-server01                         1/1     Running   236 (55m ago)   364d   175.211.213.121   server01      <none>           <none>
kube-apiserver-server01               1/1     Running   234 (55m ago)   364d   175.211.213.121   server01      <none>           <none>
kube-controller-manager-server01      1/1     Running   15 (55m ago)    364d   175.211.213.121   server01      <none>           <none>
kube-proxy-6rs8g                      1/1     Running   1 (128d ago)    299d   175.211.213.122   server02      <none>           <none>
kube-proxy-lfks4                      1/1     Running   13 (55m ago)    364d   175.211.213.121   server01      <none>           <none>
kube-proxy-r6nkn                      1/1     Running   4 (128d ago)    364d   175.211.213.124   server04      <none>           <none>
kube-proxy-xlzzf                      1/1     Running   6 (128d ago)    364d   175.211.213.123   server03      <none>           <none>
kube-scheduler-server01               1/1     Running   15 (55m ago)    364d   175.211.213.121   server01      <none>           <none>
```

```
$ kubectl describe node server01
Conditions:
  Type                 Status    LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason              Message
  ----                 ------    -----------------                 ------------------                ------              -------
  NetworkUnavailable   False     Sun, 24 Sep 2023 07:57:38 +0530   Sun, 24 Sep 2023 07:57:38 +0530   FlannelIsUp         Flannel is running on this node
  MemoryPressure       Unknown   Tue, 12 Dec 2023 11:04:12 +0530   Tue, 12 Dec 2023 11:09:22 +0530   NodeStatusUnknown   Kubelet stopped posting node status.
  DiskPressure         Unknown   Tue, 12 Dec 2023 11:04:12 +0530   Tue, 12 Dec 2023 11:09:22 +0530   NodeStatusUnknown   Kubelet stopped posting node status.
  PIDPressure          Unknown   Tue, 12 Dec 2023 11:04:12 +0530   Tue, 12 Dec 2023 11:09:22 +0530   NodeStatusUnknown   Kubelet stopped posting node status.
  Ready                Unknown   Tue, 12 Dec 2023 11:04:12 +0530   Tue, 12 Dec 2023 11:09:22 +0530   NodeStatusUnknown   Kubelet stopped posting node status.
```

```
$ journalctl -u kubelet
Jan 30 14:51:44 server01  kubelet[2172]: E0130 14:51:44.950895    2172 cni.go:362] "Error adding pod to network" err="loadFlannelSubnetEnv failed: open /run/flannel/subnet.env: no such file or directory" pod="kube-system/coredns-bd6b6df9f-4gc8m" podSandboxID={Type:docker ID:f6d0be4aac0f8ad199f806098e13ed900586ff8eae44a6415824a1da926c3cfa} podNetnsPath="/proc/6247/ns/net" networkType="flannel" networkName="cbr0"
Jan 30 14:51:44 server01  kubelet[2172]: E0130 14:51:44.953457    2172 cni.go:362] "Error adding pod to network" err="loadFlannelSubnetEnv failed: open /run/flannel/subnet.env: no such file or directory" pod="kube-system/coredns-bd6b6df9f-9kh94" podSandboxID={Type:docker ID:49cf7e42be9c6d4f58abeeb628e72b8854716da96dd70c038f13302e54dc022c} podNetnsPath="/proc/6242/ns/net" networkType="flannel" networkName="cbr0"
Jan 30 14:51:45 server01  kubelet[2172]: E0130 14:51:45.064193    2172 remote_runtime.go:209] "RunPodSandbox from runtime service failed" err="rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container \"f6d0be4aac0f8ad199f806098e13ed900586ff8eae44a6415824a1da926c3cfa\" network for pod \"coredns-bd6b6df9f-4gc8m\": networkPlugin cni failed to set up pod \"coredns-bd6b6df9f-4gc8m_kube-system\" network: loadFlannelSubnetEnv failed: open /run/flannel/subnet.env: no such file or directory"
```

kubelet service on all worker servers it shows below.

```
# systemctl status kubelet
● kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
             └─10-kubeadm.conf
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2024-01-30 15:36:36 IST; 3s ago
       Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/
    Process: 30089 ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 30089 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

I have rebooted the servers and executed `swapoff -a` still couldn't solve the issue. So do let me know further how do i debug the issue to resolve this issue?

Comment: `NotReady` may be caused when CNI plugin isn't working properly and looking at error it's probably this